# Creating a Token issue no confirmations

Tags: contract-development

Hello can somebody help me I am creating my token and I am using code bellow but I allredy created 5 same tokens and none of it is confirmed always stay "creating contract..." and 0 confirmations.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;
uint256 public totalSupply;

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constrctor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
 */
function MyToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol
) {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require(_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
 *
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other ccount
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
    Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
}
```

How to solve this am I sending low gas or ether do I even need to send ether? How can I delete previous contracts or return or something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in mainnet or testnet? Is your node fully synced?

Comment: Mainnet, and yes node fully synced

Comment: You can use http://ethgasstation.info/ to check the average gas price. If it is too low your transaction will no be confirmed quickly. If the first transaction is stuck the following will also be stuck until the first is mined. You can try replacing it setting a bigger gas price, check if your wallets support replacing a pending transaction.

Comment: I looked to that but my gas was even more than that what it say... gwei was 43

Comment: With that price it should confirm pretty quick. Try restarting your node.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ethereum is really buggy. al solved now after many deleting and redownloading blockchain and all thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Is this for testing purposes? If so please do this on the testnet or a private chain.  If you don't intend using this contract later on it will needlessly bloat the main chain.

Comment: not for testing I want to make token and start using it. I look to https://ethereum.org/token and everything is good till the "Click on the link that says Admin page and you'll be taken the simplest central bank dashboard in the world, where you can do anything you want with your newly created currency." this I dont get as it is still waiting confirmations which are 0/12

Answer (score 0):

Im using Mac OS Sierra, I had a similar problem and basically solved it the same way by completely removing the Ethereum folder from

```
Library>Ethereum
```

Then I moved Mist to the trash, emptied it, restarted my laptop and reinstalled Mist again. Finally after creating another test account, getting some more test Ether from the Rinkeby faucet and re-submitting another contract (the same one from before), Rinkeby started processing confirmations normally again. (see screenshot)

[image]

[Mist - Rinkeby Test Net - No Longer Sending Confirmations](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35670/mist-rinkeby-test-net-no-longer-sending-confirmations)

Comment: Hi there. Link-only answers are discouraged as the link could go dead or be moved at any time. Could you summarise the main steps from the article in your answer?