# Mist - Rinkeby Test Net - No Longer Sending Confirmations

Tags: mist, testnets, crowdsale, rinkeby, confirmations

Im sure this is a very simple problem that one of the brilliant geniuses on this site should be able to answer! I have been testing a sample crowdsale  using the Tutorials on https://ethereum.org/crowdsale.
I have been able to successfully create contracts, accounts, transfer tokens, transfer ethers and get a crowdsale working on the Solo Net as well as the Rinkeby Test Net using Mist 0.9.3. As recently as this morning the Rinkeby Test Net was working normally. However within the past couple hours all of a sudden the Rinkeby Test Net is no longer processing confirmations for me.

[image: Mist Rinkeby Screenshot]

As you can see from the screenshot, I am fully synced and connected to the Rinkeby Test Net with 6 Peers. As far as I can see, the Test Net should still be processing my confirmations normally but the last four transactions I initiated all still show 0 of 12 confirmations.  I tried deleting and reinstalling Mist but nothing has changed. My suspicions are that this problem is related to a cache issue or a network issue. If anyone here has a clue as to why Rinkeby Test Net is no longer working on Mist it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Mist is no longer an active project in the Ethereum ecosystem for years, and there are no plans to resurrect it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up completely removing the Ethereum folder from

```
Library>Ethereum
```

Then I moved Mist to the trash, emptied it, restarted my laptop and reinstalled Mist again. Finally after creating another test account, getting some more test Ether from the Rinkeby faucet and re-submitting another contract (the same one from before), Rinkeby started processing confirmations normally again. (see screenshot)  I dont know what the cause of this problem was other than ***Ethereum is just buggy and annoying?***

[image: Ethereum Screenshot]

The one step I wished I had done before deleting the Library>Ethereum folder was to backup my accounts in Mist by going to

```
File>Backup>Accounts
```

That way at least I would not have had to use the Rinkeby faucet again for test Ethers. Using Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: Which kind of sync were you using, regular or Light mode? You have provided insufficient information in order to debug the issue. 
Next time this happens, please add the node.log file, along with Geth version.